# Help simplifying multipolygons in geodjango

Tags: geometry, simplify, geodjango

I have a few multipolygons that have several hundred points in them. I'm looking to create less complex "thumbnails" polygons.

Naturally I'm attempting to use the [simplify](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#django.contrib.gis.geos.GEOSGeometry.simplify) method, which is supposed to apply the [Ramer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm). However, it doesn't seem to be working:

```
>>> m = Multipolygon.objects.get(id=1)
>>> m.geometry.num_points
1007
>>> m.geometry.simplify(0).num_points
1007
>>> m.geometry.simplify(1).num_points
0
>>> m.geometry.simplify(0.5).num_points
0
>>> m.geometry.simplify(10).num_points
0
```

I'm clearly missing something. When I simplify, I either get the original polygon back or an empty one, depending on the tolerance value that I use. How is the tolerance parameter supposed to work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The tolerance value is specified in map units: if two points are within the snapping tolerance, they are collapsed. So if you have geographic coordinates, `simplify(1)` would collapse everything to the nearest degree. Try something like `simplify(0.0001)` to start, or smaller depending on the resolution of your input data.

You may also be interested in [this snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1559/), which allows you to specify precision as a number of points to retain in the output geometry.

Comment: Thanks! All of my values are in lat/lng (wgs84), and nearby points are probably within 100m, so a tolerance of 1 degree is way too much! The snippet is great too, that was going to be my followup question.